# Getting filters used in KendoUI Grid

Tags: telerik, kendo-ui

In KendoUI, I have a grid with filters on. I am more interested in knowing all the filters used by user for saving purpose so that next time user comes in, they can be auto-fill. How do I get all the filters used?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Not sure how your code looks but you should be able to get the Grid's datasource object and call the method filter() to get the currently applied datasource filters. Take a look at the example below taken from [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-filter):

```html
<script>
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: [
    { name: "Jane Doe" },
    { name: "John Doe" }
  ],
  filter: { field: "name", operator: "startswith", value: "Jane" }
});
var filter = dataSource.filter();
console.log(filter.logic);  // displays "and"
console.log(filter.filters[0]); // displays '{field: "name", operator: "startswith", value: "Jane"}'
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I was looking for. Somehow I missed that in their documentation.

Comment: for some reason this is always undefined for me. I'm using MVC Kendo though but accessing via JS Api.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to the answers above - if you want to do it purely on the front end without even targeting the actual data source - your can use the following...

```
var myGrid = $("#gridname").data("kendoGrid");
myGrid.dataSource.filter().filters[0];
```

You can than break this up into different parameters ...

```
myGrid.dataSource.filter().filters[0].field
myGrid.dataSource.filter().filters[0].operator
myGrid.dataSource.filter().filters[0].value
```

Hope this helps - cheers

Answer (score 2):

My configuration is MVC with the data being fetched server-side. What I mean is that the grid calls this method to get its data:

```
public ActionResult Documents_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, 
        int documentType = (int)ApiGlobals.TrxTypes.חשבונית)
```

What I do is simple:
I capture the request object in a Session variable and then use the session variable whenever I need it. In the following example I use the filter to print only the documents filtered in the grid:

```
    public ActionResult Documents_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, 
        int documentType = (int)ApiGlobals.TrxTypes.חשבונית)
    {
       Session["DocumentListFilter"] = request;
       ...
    }

    public ActionResult PrintListKendo(int documentType)
    {           
        DataSourceRequest request  = (DataSourceRequest)Session["DocumentListFilter"];

        if (request == null)
        {
            request = new DataSourceRequest();
        }

        request.Page = 1;
        request.PageSize = int.MaxValue;

        IQueryable<Document> data = _db.GetDocuments()
           .Where(d => d.TrxTypeId == (int)documentType);

        DataSourceResult filteredData = data.ToDataSourceResult<Document, DocumentListSingleDocumentViewModel>(request,
            d => ViewModelFactory.Create(d));

        //... call the reporting package with the data, etc.
      }
```

You can save the request object (=serialize it, or save it properties) to the database and reload it when the user opens the relevant page and the grid fetched its data,